To Wait Or Not To Wait: Optimal Strategy for Finding a Parking Spot?
Today, I was driving around a busy parking lot with my family member and we started having the age old debate:

Strategy 1: Is it better to wait at a single parking spot and wait for this spot to free up?

Strategy 2: Or is it better to drive around the parking lot and wait for a parking spot to free up?


I am trying to model this problem mathematically to understand which approach is better. I tried to analyze two different scenarios. In both scenarios, when you arrive, the parking lot has infinite spots and all spots are full

Scenario 1: Each spot can be freed with probability $\sim\exp (\lambda_1)$ and can be filled with probability  $\sim \exp(\lambda_2)$
Scenario 2: Each spot has a probability $\sim \exp(\lambda_i)$ where $\lambda_i$ $\sim$ poisson $(z)$  of freeing and a probability $\sim \exp(\lambda_j)$ where $\lambda_j$ $\sim$ poisson $(y)$  of freeing


Scenario 1:
$\lambda_1$: Rate at which cars leave a spot
$\lambda_2$: Rate at which cars fill a spot
Strategy 1: The time needed to wait for a spot to become free follows an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda_1$. Thus, the expected waiting time is:
$$E[T_{wait}] = \frac{1}{\lambda_1}$$
Strategy 2: My logic is that as you drive, each spot you pass has a probability of being free. This probability is the same for each spot and is equal to the steady-state probability of a spot being empty in a system where spots become occupied and free according to the given rates.
Let the steady-state probability of a spot being empty $p$. In equilibrium, the following condition must hold for the parking lot to be full on average:
$$\lambda_1(1-p) = \lambda_2p$$
Solving for $p$:
$$p = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$$
Zooming out for a second, we can analyze this further. Suppose there is a probability $p$ that any given spot is empty. Then:
$$X = \text{number of spots checked until finding an empty one}$$
$$P(X = k) = \text{probability of finding an empty spot on the k-th try}$$
This means: The first $(k-1)$ spots were occupied with probability $(1-p)$ each and the $k$-th spot is empty with probability $p$
We can express this mathematically as:
$$P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1} \cdot p$$
This is a PMF of a geometric distribution with parameter $p$.
The number of spots you need to check before finding an empty one follows a geometric distribution with parameter $p$.
The expected number of spots you need to check is (i.e. invoking the geometric distribution):
$$E[N] = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}{\lambda_1}$$
Finally, lets assume that checking each spot takes a fixed time $t$, then the expected time to find a free spot is:
$$E[T_{drive}] = \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}{\lambda_1} \cdot t$$
Comparison:
The driving strategy is better if $E[T_{drive}] < E[T_{wait}]$, i.e., if:
$$\frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}{\lambda_1} \cdot t < \frac{1}{\lambda_1}$$
Simplifying:
$$(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)t < 1$$
$$t < \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$$
Therefore, the driving strategy is better if the time $t$ to check each spot is less than $\frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$. Otherwise, waiting at one spot is better. It seems that if you can check spots very quickly (small $t$), driving is better. If checking spots takes a long time, or if the rates of cars leaving and arriving are high, waiting becomes the better strategy.

Scenario 2:
Strategy 1:
Strategy 1: Wait at one spot
Given a spot with departure rate $\lambda_i$, the waiting time follows an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda_i$. The expected waiting time, conditioned on $\lambda_i$, is:
$$E[T_{wait}|\lambda_i] = \frac{1}{\lambda_i}$$
Herem $\lambda_i$ itself is a random variable following a Poisson distribution with mean $z$. To find the unconditional expected waiting time, I think we can use the law of total expectation:
$$E[T_{wait}] = E_{\lambda_i}[E[T_{wait}|\lambda_i]] = E_{\lambda_i}[\frac{1}{\lambda_i}]$$
Expanding this using the probability mass function of the Poisson distribution:
$$E[T_{wait}] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \cdot P(\lambda_i = k)$$
$$E[T_{wait}] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{z^k e^{-z}}{k!}$$
I think we can analyze this sum numerically. We evaluate many different values of $k$ and see which value of $k$ results in the highest probability.
Strategy 2:
For this strategy, we again need to find the steady-state probability of a random spot being empty, considering that each spot has its own random rates $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$.
For a given spot with rates $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$, the steady-state probability of being empty is:
$$p(\lambda_i, \lambda_j) = \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i + \lambda_j}$$
To find the overall probability of a random spot being empty, we need to average this over all possible $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$:
$$p = E_{\lambda_i, \lambda_j}[p(\lambda_i, \lambda_j)] = E_{\lambda_i, \lambda_j}[\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i + \lambda_j}]$$
Expanding this using the probability mass functions of the Poisson distributions for $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$:
$$p = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{i}{i+j} \cdot \frac{z^i e^{-z}}{i!} \cdot \frac{y^j e^{-y}}{j!}$$
This double sum is the final equation for the probability of a spot being empty (need to be evaluated numerically).
Once we have this probability $p$, the expected number of spots to check before finding an empty one should again follow a geometric distribution:
$$E[N] = \frac{1}{p}$$
And the expected time to find a free spot, assuming a fixed time $t$ to check each spot, is:
$$E[T_{drive}] = \frac{t}{p}$$
Comparison:
To compare the two strategies, we need to analyze the new inequality:
$$E[T_{drive}] < E[T_{wait}]$$
Substituting:
$$\frac{t}{p} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{z^k e^{-z}}{k!}$$
Or:
$$t < p \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{z^k e^{-z}}{k!}$$
Where $p = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{i}{i+j} \cdot \frac{z^i e^{-z}}{i!} \cdot \frac{y^j e^{-y}}{j!}$

Have I done this correctly?

In practice, Strategy 2 is chosen simply because we must keep moving to not block other people. If we can choose Strategy 1, we need to find a place where we can have a largest views (the number of parking spots observed is maximum).

@ NN2: haha, I agree! otherwise other cars will start blowing their horns lol!
